# Javascript, CSS, jQuery - my canvas moves to where it shouldnt be

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

Problem is in title. It used to do it on the odd occasion. Then i added the jQuery rotate.js plugin to spin my heading 360 degrees and now it is constantly placed to the right of where it should be. It may be interesting to note that i got the offset of the canvas with

```
var rect = gameController.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var offset = {
    x: rect.left,
    y: rect.top
};
```

And that still has coordinates of 0,0 in the top left corner of where it should be ( which is correct and how it should be when the canvas has not moved).

```
#canvas {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 52px;
    margin-left: 44px;
    background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
}
```

If the position is absolute, it is removed from the document and nothing will make it move. Strange.

Comment: It's necessary to see all the code, including the html. Can you post it to jsfiddle or pastebin?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F9cYv/ thats a start. i don't know how to use jsfiddle that well

Answer (score 1):

getBoundingClientRect() returns the sum of the canvas and its css border-boxes.

Maybe check the canvas with getClientRects() to see exactly where it is.

Comment: This is so weird but i tried your suggestion like this `alert(gameController.canvas.getClientRects());` and it did not alert the position, it said object client rect list, but it fixed the problem, just alerting something fixed the problem :-S (not that i want to have an alert on page load)

Comment: It is to do with when stuff gets loaded because i tried using window.onload with all my scripts so i could put them in the head and the same thing happend ( the canvas moved to the right ). alerting something before the canvas loads helps it get setup properly, it gives it more time for other stuff to load

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it moved, i probably have a css error somewhere..but i had my canvas as position absolute, relative to a div that it was inside. I placed my canvas right at the top of the body tag so it was absolute, relative to the whole page, then changed the placement of it with top and bottom to get it correct. Now nothing will move it. It works fine with the rotate.js plugin. Thanks for having a look at my question.